# How to disable Warning error flag in yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

How to disable the warnings which considered as error in yocto BITBAKE recipe.

error: '' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]

Comment: Maybe easiest way is to patch the source code to fix uninitialized variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more compilation flags as below on your recipes.

```
TARGET_CFLAGS += -Wuninitialized
TARGET_CFLAGS += -Wmaybe-uninitialized
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is to clean the package and then rebuild it. For example, if it's u-boot that has the tainted flag:

```
$ bitbake -c cleanall u-boot
$ bitbake u-boot
```